# Designing a non-inverting buck-boost converter

Tags: power-supply, transistors, switches, circuit-design, converter

I am trying to design a non-inverting buck-boost converter using 4 switches (transistors).
[image]

Note:The schematic is taken from Texas instruments.

This can be summarized in the following points:

1- The non-inverting buck-boost converter usually comes with two-switches and two diodes. However, I will replace the two diodes with two transistors and that is known as a four switch buck-boost converter.

2- I would like to choose the values of the parameters but I have one issue which is that I could not find a good reference with the relevant equations that will help me to calculate the parameters. Therefore, Could you provide a good reference where I can find the equations or the equations themselves.

3- The input range of the converter will be big like 8v-70v and I want to regulate the voltage to say 12V and the switching frequency will be high 100khz or even greater than that to achieve a higher frequency. (to offer a step-up and step-down)

4- Can I simulate the converter in simulink even though the four switches may need to operate on a complementary (for example,as I understood,we will have two different duty cycles D1 and D2 and these need to have different values if we want to operate the converter efficiently).

Can someone please answer my questions. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Will try to answer today, but yes you can use Simulink

Answer (score 3):

> *Could you provide a good reference where I can find the equations or
> the equations themselves*

No because that's a shopping question mixed with a question that solicits opinions and both will attract question closure.

If you are designing a synchronous buck-boost converter (4 transistors) then presumably you know how to design a synchronous buck converter and you know how to design a synchronous boost converter as individual items. If you don't know how to do this then your question will probably also be closed on the basis that you need to focus.

> *The input range of the converter will be big like 8v-70v and I want to
> regulate the voltage to say 12V*

So, assuming that you are still reading, consider this: -

- For \$V_{IN}\$ up to 12 volts, SW1 is on and SW3 is off. SW4 and SW2 act as a synchronous boost converter: -

[image]

You don't need further explanation of this do you. If you say yes then you have read too far.

- For \$V_{IN}\$ above 12 volts, SW2 is on and SW4 is off. SW1 and SW3 act as a synchronous buck converter: -

[image]

You don't need further explanation of this do you. If you say yes then you have read too far.

> *Can I simulate the converter in simulink*

Simulink can simulate this circuit as far as I know.